# Subset a data frame based on another

Tags: r

I have two data frames, x and y.

```
x<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), g=c(21,52,43,94,35))
y<-data.frame(id=c(3,4,7), u=c(55, 77, 99))
```

I want to subset x to include only the observations with "IDs" that are also in y.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setdiff` to exclude observations appearing in both df

```
> x[setdiff(x$id, y$id),]  
  id  g
1  1 21
2  2 52
5  5 35
```

Use `merge` to include observations present in both df

```
> merge(x, y)
  id  g  u
1  3 43 55
2  4 94 77
```

or looking for this subset?

```
> x[intersect(x$id, y$id),]
  id  g
3  3 43
4  4 94
```

Comment: Your third example was exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: As the other answerer mentions the `intersect` solution only works by luck. You are subsetting by the ids themselves instead of the indices.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer only works because the values 3 and 4 in x$id happen to be located in rows 3 and 4. The wrong answer will be obtained, for example, if:

```
x<-data.frame(id=c(1,3,2,4,5), g=c(21,52,43,94,35))
x[intersect(x$id, y$id),]
  id  g
3  2 43
4  4 94
```

The following will work properly, regardless of the position of the common elements:

```
x[is.element(x$id,intersect(x$id,y$id)),]
```

Comment: Nice catch. But the correct fix would be to use the merge solution and avoid `intersect` altogether. Posting a comment under the other answer would suffice.

Comment: The OP wants to subset x.  merge(x,y) returns y$u.

Comment: Okay I see that now. But that is still better than intersect. `merge(x, y['id'])`