# Subset a data frame based on another 2

Tags: r, subset

Trying to implement an answer to the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702733/subset-a-data-frame-based-on-another) , but can't see where I'm going wrong.

I am trying to extract from one dataframe observations listed in another dataframe using a common field.  The question cited was not exactly the same but an answer suggested using "setdiff" for the related question, which seems to fit my need.

Here's the example I set up to try it:

```
    # orginal dataframe
    origdf <- data.frame(apple = c(111, 2, 4, "fox"), 
             orange=c( 222, 11, 12, 14), 
             pear=c( "one", "two", 10, 11),
             peach=c("which", "way", "to", "go"),
             banana=c(333, 22, 23, 24),
             grape=c(77, 78, 79, 80))
    origdf
    # a separate process produces a dataframe with observations to be extracted from the original dataframe
    extract <- origdf[which(origdf$apple == 111 |
                origdf$apple == "fox"), ]
    extract
    test <- origdf[setdiff(origdf$apple, extract$apple)]
    test

    # the above returns an error that "undefined columns selected", but the following works...
    origdf$apple
    extract$apple
```

Why am I having this problem?

Comment: You missed a comma: `test <- origdf[setdiff(origdf$apple, extract$apple),]`. Without it, R thinks that you are subsetting columns, which you obviously are not.

Comment: Silly mistake, no?  But I was expecting to see rows 2 and 3 remaining after the extract, but instead I see rows 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you received an error because you missed a comma in:

```
test <- origdf[setdiff(origdf$apple, extract$apple)]
```

Without it, R thinks that you are subsetting columns. Hence *"undefined columns selected"*.

Your second issue is with the use of `setdiff` for indexing. When subsetting the rows of a data.frame, you need to either provide indices or a logical vector indicating whether a specific row should be included in the final subset. The following, however,

```
setdiff(origdf$apple, extract$apple)
```

returns:

```
[1] "2" "4"
```

This will be implicitly coerced to `c(2, 4)` when calling:

```
test <- origdf[setdiff(origdf$apple, extract$apple),]
```

since R thinks you are subsetting by index. Therefore returning:

```
  apple orange pear peach banana grape
2     2     11  two   way     22    78
4   fox     14   11    go     24    80
```

To return what you actually want, you can use `%in%` which returns a logical vector of whether `origdf$apple` is *in* the `setdiff`:

```
test <- origdf[origdf$apple %in% setdiff(origdf$apple, extract$apple),]
```

returns:

```
  apple orange pear peach banana grape
2     2     11  two   way     22    78
3     4     12   10    to     23    79
```

An alternative would be to check whether `origd$apple` is `%in%` `extract$apple` and return rows that are not (`!`):

```
test <- origdf[!origdf$apple %in% extract$apple,]
```

Comment: So I both make a silly mistake and picked an unfortunate example!  thanks.

Comment: @WBarker Glad that my solution helped. If you think that this answers your question, you may accept it by clicking on the grey check mark under the downvote button :)

Comment: @ useR It did work.  Continuing my research, it appears that the following also works: require(dplyr); anti_join(origdf,extract)  (not sure how to add code in comments section).